# How to Tweet with 'image' using Twitter gem from rails4 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

I'm doing a tutorial project Automated-Post-scheduler, with app complete a user could schedule posts with text content to a social network provider (Facebook/Twitter).

I added images to posts using paperclip so users can attach an image to a post.

Here is my question: **How do i post to Twitter with text content and the image ?**

The current code only posts the 'content'. I had a read at the twitter doc's and have tried client.update_with_media(), but i can't work this one one out. Please help I'm stuk.

Relevant Code : using the Twitter gem - rails4

posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_post, only: [:cancel]

def new
    if current_user.connections.any?
        @post = Post.new
    else
        redirect_to dashboard_path, notice: "Please connect to a social network first"
    end
end

def create
    @post = current_user.posts.new(post_params)

    respond_to do |format|
        if @post.save
            format.html {redirect_to dashboard_path, notice: "Post was successfully created."}
        else
            format.html { render :new }
        end
    end
end

def cancel
    @post.update_attributes(state: "canceled")
    redirect_to dashboard_path, notice: "Post was successfully canceled"
end

private

def set_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:content, :scheduled_at, :state, :user_id, :facebook, :twitter, :image)
end
```

post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
has_attached_file :image, styles: { thumb: "100x100>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
validates_presence_of :content
validates_presence_of :scheduled_at
validates_length_of :content, maximum: 140, message: "less than 140 please"
validates_datetime :scheduled_at, :on => :create, :on_or_after => Time.zone.now
after_create :schedule

def schedule
    begin
        ScheduleJob.set(wait_until: scheduled_at).perform_later(self)
        self.update_attributes(state: "scheduled")
    rescue Exception => e
        self.update_attributes(state: "scheduling error", error: e.message)
    end
end

def display
    begin
        unless state == "canceled"
            if facebook == true
                to_facebook
            end
            if twitter == true
                to_twitter
            end
        end
        self.update_attributes(state: "posted")
    rescue Exception => e
        self.update_attributes(state: "posting error", error: e.message)
    end
end

def to_twitter
    client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
        config.access_token = self.user.twitter.oauth_token
        config.access_token_secret = self.user.twitter.secret
        config.consumer_key = ENV['TWITTER_KEY']
        config.consumer_secret = ENV['TWITTER_SECRET']
    end
    client.update(self.content)
end

def to_facebook
    graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(self.user.facebook.oauth_token)
    graph.put_connections("me", "feed", message: self.content)
end
```

The same issue with *Facebook*.. any help appreciated.

Comment: Please help i am new to development, but for an experienced Ruby on Rail's dev this should be like a stroll in the park!  Any help appreciated.

Comment: You have provided loads of code but you haven't explained what your issue is exactly. Please edit your question and add that information, and other might be able to help you better.